# The convexity of a stochastic integral with respect to the initial condition

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B(t)$ be the standard Brownian motion,
$$dx(t) = \mu(x(t),t)\,dt+\sigma(x(t),t)\,dB(t),$$
where $\mu(x,t)$ and $\sigma(x,t)$ satisfy the usual conditions laid out e.g. on [the Wikipedia page on the existence and almost sure uniqueness of the t-continuous sample path solution of a stochastic differential equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions). $f(x)$ is convex in $x$. Is $\mathbf E[f(x(t))|x(0)]$ convex with respect to $x(0)$?

---

1. I can show if $f$ increases, $\mathbf E[f]$ increases in $x(0)$ by looking at path $x(t,\omega)$ for each sample $\omega$. By the Markovness and the uniqueness of the t-continuous sample path solution $x(t,\omega)$ given the initial condition $x(0,\omega)$, $x_1(0,\omega)\le x_2(0,\omega) \Longleftrightarrow x_1(t,\omega)\le x_2(t,\omega) \Longleftrightarrow f(x_1(t,\omega))\le f(x_2(t,\omega))$. Taking the expectation on both sides generates the desired result. Can we do something similar to answer the question?
2. As an alternative, I applied Ito's lemma to $f(x)$
   $$f(x(t)) = f(x(0)) +\int_0^t \Big(\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Big)\,d\tau+\int_0^t \sigma\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dB_\tau,$$
   and
   $$\mathbf E_{t=0}[f(x(t))]=f(x(0)) +\int_0^t \mathbf E\Big[\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Big]\,d\tau$$
   The first term on the right hand side of the above equation is obviously convex with respect to $x(0)$. However, what can one say about the $x(0)$ dependency of the remaining terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is affirmative if $\mu$ is independent of $x$.

**Proof:**

Define $x(t)$ as a stochastic path and
$$u(x,t):=\mathbf E[f(x(T))|x(t)=x].$$
By [the Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), which is derived from the tower theorem of the expectation
$$u(x,t) = \mathbf E[\mathbf E[f(x(T))|x(s)]|x(t)=x]=\mathbf E[u(x(s),s)|x(t)=x].$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0.$$
Differentiating PDE with respect to $x$, and using subscript $1$ on a function to denote the partial differentiation with respect to $x$ of that function, we obtain
$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial t}+(\mu+\sigma\sigma_1)\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}+\mu_1u_1=0.$$
Again by [the Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), this is equivalent to
$$u_1(x,t)=\mathbf E\big[e^{\int_t^s\mu_1}u_1(x(s),s)\big|x(t)\big]=E\big[e^{\int_t^T\mu_1}f'(x(T))\big|x(t)=x\big],$$
under the probability measure such that $x$ is an Ito process driven by
$$dx = (\mu+\sigma\sigma_1)\,dt+\sigma\,dB_t.$$
Note that now the current $x$ is a different Ito process with the drift different from the one described in the question.

Now we use the condition that $\mu_1=0$. Then $u_1(x,t)=\mathbf E\big[f'(x(T))\big|x(t)=x\big]$.

We apply method 1 mentioned in the question. Since $f'$ increases, $\mathbf E\big[f'(x(t)\,\big|\,x(0)\big]$ increases in $x(0)$ by looking at path $x(t,\omega)$ for each sample $\omega$. By the Markovness of $x(t,\omega)$ stemming from it being a diffusion and the P-almost surely uniqueness of t-continuous sample path,
$$x_1(0,\omega)\le x_2(0,\omega) \Longleftrightarrow x_1(t,\omega)\le x_2(t,\omega) \Longleftrightarrow f'(x_1(t,\omega))\le f'(x_2(t,\omega)).$$
Taking the expectation on both sides arrives at the convexity of $\mathbf E\big[f(x(T))\big|x(0)\big]$ with respect to $x(0)$.

---

The answer is also affirmative if we can transform $x$ into something that makes the effective $\mu_1=0$ and $f$ transformed still convex.

Comment: The tower theorem of conditional expectation that I am familiar with says
that for $t\le s$,
$$
\mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(x(T))|{\cal F}_s]|{\cal F}_t]=\mathbb E[f(x(T))|{\cal F}_t].
$$
Can you elaborate how this relates to your formula
$$
u(x,t) = \mathbf E[\mathbf E[f(x(T))|x(s)]|x(t)=x]=\mathbf E[u(x(s),s)|x(t)=x] ?
$$

Comment: @KurtG.: Substituting the definition of $u(x,t)$ into my equation you quote gets you the first equation you wrote.

Comment: @KurtG.: Is it clear?

Comment: Not really. That formula I was asking about in the comment is probably true. Do you use it at all ? I am now having trouble to understand your statement that $x_1(0,\omega)<x_2(0,\omega)\Leftrightarrow x_1(t,\omega)<x_2(t,\omega)$ . When $\mu$ or $\sigma$ depend on $x$ I don't easily see that this is true.

Comment: @KurtG.: That statement is actually used in the derivation of Feynman-Kac formula and thus is subsumed by the latter. As for the inequality, it is implied by the P-almost sure uniqueness of the stochastic differential equation solution.  I added the link to the Wikipedia page on the existence and P-almost sure uniqueness of each sample path.

Comment: Consider the [reducible SDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Reducible_SDEs:_Case_1) where $f(x)<0$. This implies $h'<0$ (i.e. $h$ is strictly decreasing). Consequently the inverse function $h^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing. This implies that for $x_1(0,\omega)<x_2(0,\omega)$ we should have $x_1(t,\omega)\color{red}{>}x_2(t,\omega)$ for every $t>0$.

Comment: @KurtG.: Did you see the $h$ inside $h^{-1}$?

Comment: Ah sorry. Point taken. Can you elaborate why the strict inequality $<$ for $t$ follows from pathwise uniqueness ?

Comment: @KurtG.: Because otherwise the two t-continuous sample paths with positive probability measure, by the intermediate value theorem, cross each other. At the crossing point, there will be two distinct paths emanating from the same point, contradicting the uniqueness property of the sample path. The inequality is not necessarily strict though if $\sigma$ is not bound from below by a positive function.

Comment: Convincing. I fixed what I believe was a typo in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks complicated in general. Writing
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathbf{E}[f(x(t))]=f(x(0))+\mathbf{E}\Bigg[\int_0^t\Big(\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big)(x(s))+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\sigma\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Big)(x(s))\,ds\Bigg]
\end{align}
we can replace $x(s)$ by $x_0+\int_0^s\mu(x(r))\,dr+\int_0^s\sigma(x(r))\,dB(r)$ and repeat that with $x(r)$ and so on. We will never be able to reach a simple expression that shows how that second part depends on $x_0$.

A typical example where we know the convexity of the expectation on the LHS of (1) is the Black-Scholes formula where
\begin{align}
f(x)&=(x-K)^+\,,\quad\mu(x)=rx\,,\quad\sigma(x)=\sigma x\,,\\[3mm]
\mathbf{E}[f(x(t))]&=e^{rt}x_0\Phi(d_1)-K\Phi(d_2)\,,\\[3mm]
d_{1,2}&=\frac{\log(x_0/K)+rt\pm\sigma^2t/2}{\sigma\sqrt{t}}\,,\\[3mm]
\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}[f(x(t))]}{\partial x_0}&=e^{rt}\Phi(d_1)>0\,.
\end{align}
To derive this we use the known lognormal distribution of the stock price $x(t)$.

Comment: This is not a general proof. The answer is affirmative. See my proof shown in my answer.